# Auto-update and launcher integration - install4j

Tags: install4j

I am trying to integrate install4j updater application to be part of start menu (in Windows). So that user can go to Start->Programs->AppName->Update and start updater.

I tried with "Launcher integration" option (I created launcher who points to batch file with only one echo command which is doing nothing) and setup my updater to be invoked whenever this launcher is invoked (launcher exists in the Start menu).

But when I start launcher from the Start menu, updater doesn't appear, no errors, no logs and launcher is executed (echo message).

Is there any other way or I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to integrate install4j updater application to be part of
>   start menu (in Windows). So that user can go to
>   Start->Programs->AppName->Update and start updater.

Presumably you have a "Create program group" action in your "Installation" screen. In the configuration of that action, activate the "Windows program group entries" tab and add a file link to the updater.